# How to call a number from an android widget

Tags: android, android-intent, android-widget

I'm trying to make a widget which calls a phone number which is stored in sharedpreferences. I tried some ways, but I am quite a beginner in java and I don't know how to make it. Actually the problem is that I don't really know what context is and when I want to start intent with startActivity(intent); Intellij underlines it as an error.
Here is the code:

```
package com.example;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class widgetCode extends AppWidgetProvider{
    public void callHelp() {
        SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String callnum = app_preferences.getString("callnum", "");
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+callnum));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

I would call callHelp() from android:onclick in xml.

There is also an error at "this" in getDefaultSharedPreferences(this). It would be also welcome if anyone explains me widget lifecycle.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: `getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)` needs a valid context. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences(android.content.Context)

Answer (score 0):

A Context is an Android object that provides access to a lot of system services and abilities.  Every Activity and every Service is a Context.  The this in getDefaultSharedPreferences is a Context.  Basically that code was written expecting to be called directly in your Activity.

In your case, you're writing an AppWidgetProvider, which is a subclass of BroadcastReceiver.  In a BroadcastReceiver, you're passed a Context when onReceive is called.  You need to pass that into callHelp.  If necessary you may need to save it in a class variable so its still around when needed.

Comment: Thanks, but how to do that? I am a complete beginner and I would be glad if someone helped me, because I'm developing this for some tournament. ;)

Comment: Override the onReceive function, and store the Context that's passed in into a variable.  Then use it whenever you need a Context in the future.

Comment: Okay so I must add onRecieve() somewhere and then where to put @override? And how to get that context out of it?